# How to make a list out of the attribute of objects from a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Yesterday I was wondering how to access to dictionary keys in a DataFrame column ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500328/retrieving-a-list-from-a-specific-value-with-a-dictionnary-as-column-type)). The solution was to use `.str[<key>]` on the pandas Series and call the `tolist()` method afterwards. However this does not work with object attributes.

My goal is to get as an output a list of a specific attributes for each object in a panda Series.

Here is a sample code with the solution I am working with. I cast the whole object Series as a list and then iterate over it to get the specific attribute. Is there a way to access directly the attribute ?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [User("Juan"), User("Karen"), User("Vince")]
})


myObjects = df['col1'].tolist()
myNames = [u.name for u in myObjects]

# Desired output
['Juan', 'Karen', 'Vince']
```

And when I try the dictionary solution :

```
myNames = df["col1"].str['name'].tolist()

# Output
[nan, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) from `operator` library in combination with [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). This will map your inputs using the `attrgetter`, which returns a function that when called on the entries of `col1` retrieve object attributes named `name`. Equivalent to `lambda x: x.name`

```
from operator import attrgetter
myNames = df["col1"].map(attrgetter("name")).tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Juan', 'Karen', 'Vince']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend your method as it only works if you change the class. Alternatively, you can use `apply()` for this:

```
myNames = list(df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.name))
```

List:

```
['Juan', 'Karen', 'Vince']
```

The `str` method works only dictionaries, but not on objects. If you make your object [convertible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35282286/7947994) to a dictionary it would work. For example like this:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'name', self.name


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [User("Juan"), User("Karen"), User("Vince")]
})

result = list(df['col1'].map(dict).str['name'])
```

Comment: Yeah, the class is from a library, so the `.str[<key>]` is definitely not the option. Please note that the only reason your answer is not the accepted one is because @AndrejH's answer is a bit faster on my large DataFrame (around 20% faster).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
df['col1'].map(lambda x: x.name).to_list()
```